# '&&' and '||' operators with strings

Tags: c#, string, operators

**PLEASE DISREGARD. THIS WAS NOT PROPERLY RESEARCHED. My apologies**

I've come across this issue a fair bit and I'm not sure exactly why this is happening.

To compare two integers is fine using the `&&` and the `||` operators, as such:

```
    int a = ...;
    int b = ...;
    if (a && b == 1) { do something }
```

However, this doesn't work with strings. Instead you have to lay it out like this:

```
    string a = ...;
    string b = ...;
    if (a == "Hello" && b == "Hello") { do something }
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: I don't think this compiles. Are you sure?

Comment: I can't get this to compile either

Comment: Yeah sorry about this. Did not think that through. I was sure there was an occasion where I had used this before.

Comment: I'm assuming you previously declared the variables, and are not declaring them in-line. Is my edit better? If not, feel free to roll back.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes that was assumed. This was not taken from existing code at all

Comment: `a && b == 1` still won't compile. C# does not have implicit conversions to boolean, and `&&` cannot be applied to integers

Comment: The only thing that comes close, with both `a` and `b` of type `int`, is the legal code `if ((a & b) == 1) { ... }`, but this is with a parenthesis, and a single `&` sign. This is legal but ***does not*** mean "if `a` and `b` are both equal to `1`".

Comment: Your question was non-sense and your codes wasn't compile.Now you changed, it is more non-sense because both compile and works fine.(with a==2 or something ofcourse, it still doesn't compile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first sample doesn't work the way you think it does. You need to define it like this as well:

```
if (a == 1 && b == 1) { do something }
```

The reason the snippet seems to works is that the `a` expression is an integer, which can be implicitly converted to a boolean. You're checking whether `a` reduces to true or false in the larger expression, not whether it's equal to 1. Strings, on the other hand, do not implicitly convert to booleans, and so it fails at compile time, rather than giving wrong results at run time.

Comment: +1 for explaining implicit conversion

Comment: that if statement doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, might be missing something, but this is not a valid C# code. And C# does not have implicit conversion to booleans either.

Comment: @Selman22 I took the sample code at face value. Should be all roses now.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn now it's okey but this is not about either strings or integers.It's valid because both sides of expression returns a bool result.

Comment: I had to down-vote because "the a expression is an integer, which can be implicitly converted to a boolean" is *not* true in C#. I'm not sure why the OP claims the original code works in context, but shouldn't let such erroneous assumptions continue; C# would fail with "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'" or similar.